# Why did MacOS Classic choose the colon as a path separator?

Tags: history, mac-os-classic, file-system

I mean, all other OSs that I know of use some form of slash as a path separator, so why did Apple choose the colon?

Comment: Other OS's also provide a command line for typing out path names.

Comment: "All other OSes" that I know of include use of dot (quite a few of those), greater-than, and colon as path-name separators.  It's mainly Unix derivatives that use "/", and DOS derivatives that use "\" because "/" was already taken.

Comment: Wikipedia has an [incomplete list of path formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)). A good number don't use / or \.

Comment: What a great question! Welcome to RCSE. I'm expecting an interesting mix of historical and technical answers.

Comment: When I was a wee lad, I was familiar with CP/M, Vax/VMS and DOS, and at that time CP/M had no folders but had user areas, VMS had *proper* paths with `.` separators, and `:` as prefix delimiters, and DOS was the weirdo with backslashes. At that time, to me, VMS was the most featureful OS, so I'd be probably asking the same question, except why wouldn't paths be separated by periods :) N.B. In contrast with DCL used as the "language" of the VMS command line, the command line in CP/M and DOS felt like a bit of a joke, so it wouldn't enter my mind to treat those as any sort of a "gold standard".

Comment: I'm tolerably certain Prime's [PRIMOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRIMOS) used `>` for a directory separator, at least back in the late 70s when I used it briefly.  However, the Wikipedia page linked neither confirms nor denies that.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Colon was inherited from SOS for the Apple III**

Unlike one may assume, [MacOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_Mac_OS) (1984/01) did not inherited the colon (`:`) from Lisa OS (1983/01), which [used a hyphen](https://www.pagetable.com/?p=241) (`-`) as path separator, but from Apple III's [SOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_SOS) (1980/10), created for the [Apple III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_III) to manage the huge data pile of a 5 MiB Profile.

---

**Staircase wit:**

On colon vs. slash, Apple went not once but twice full circle:

- SOS had a colon,
- ProDOS, the direct SOS offspring for the Apple II, switched the colon for a slash (`/`) when introduced in 1983; its 16-bit follow up
- ProDOS 16 for the IIgs (as kernel of GS/OS) [reintroduced the colon](http://www.1000bit.it/support/manuali/apple/technotes/gsos/tn.gsos.04.html) for compatibility with MacOS, which in turn with
- Mac OSX - (re)introduced the slash to accommodate its Unix base system.

Comment: And the Finder (or probably, some GUI framework component) complicates matters by *still* treating `:` in a file name as a `/`.

Comment: @chepner It depends what you mean I guess, but in my mind it's kind of the opposite; Finder allows a `/` in a file name but "stores" that character as a `:` in the POSIX view of the filesystem. (Internally it actually seems to store the character as U+F022 at least via its FAT driver.)

Answer (score 27):

I think the colon deserves to be considered the original, the one true separator character.  All others are mere imitators  ;-)

My rationale for this is the seminal paper [*A General-Purpose File System For Secondary Storage*](https://multicians.org/fjcc4.html) which first laid out the conceptual design of a tree-structured file system. It used ":" to separate components in path names (and in tree names, a distinction we don't generally bother with these days).

Thus, to answer the question - I imagine that the MacOS implementers were simply following historical precedent.

When implemented in Multics, the path separator had become ">", so the honors go to the paper, not the implementation.

George 3 (for the ICL 1900 series) curiously used ":" for a username prefix, but "." for the pathname separator.  I suppose this to be similar to the way Unix interprets "~user", except that ":user" was built into the file system.

Comment: I had to give a +1 even though it is not really answering the question :))

Answer (score 25):

The original Macintosh File System did not support directories.  But the Mac did support multiple floppy drives from the start, and colon `:` was used in fairly standard fashion as a drive prefix analogous to VMS, MS-DOS and elsewhere – `Disk:File`.

This is only an educated guess, but I suspect they generalized `:` to a path separator later with HFS as it was already a reserved character for the drive specifier use.  This would prevent incompatibility with forward slash `/` being used as a valid character in existing Mac file names.

Answer (score 15):

It's not completely accurate to focus on slashes as *the* established solution — `.` was also in the mix, being DEC's choice for both TOPS and VMS.

That said, I'm going to speculate wildly that it comes down to:

- Apple's Macintosh filing systems were already fairly non-standard — supporting forked files, for example — in support of simplifying the user experience; and
- `:` makes a lot more sense to a normal non-computer user than a slash.

E.g. suppose we were important 1980s office people and I told you that I had filed a report under 'Finance: Housing', you'd assume it was in the 'housing' subcategory to 'finance'. If I told you I had filed it as 'Finance/Housing' you'd think it was in the single category that is simultaneously both finance and housing.

So the former better communicates intent.

Couple that with the fact that Macintoshes of the era couldn't even physically read the floppy disks of other machines — other disks were either 5.25" or double density, Macintoshes take 3.5" disks and the pre-SE Macintosh disk controllers can decode single density and GCR only — and there's really no good reason for hewing to slashes.

Comment: For clarity, TOPS & VMS directories used square brackets and dots.  For example, DRIVE1:[DIRA.DIRB.DIRC]SOMEFILE.EXT;32767

Comment: `.` was also the separator in the BBC Micro's [ADFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Disc_Filing_System) (which also used `$` for the root, `^` for the parent, and `@` the current directory).

Comment: @RonJohn - VMS actually accepted square brackets and angle brackets, the latter for TOPS-20 compatibility.  For some time, I used to run with 'SET DEFAULT <>' so as to discover software that foolishly assumed square brackets were the only possibility.

Comment: @another-dave very interesting.  I've used VMS for 30 years and never knew about or saw angle brackets.

Comment: You only saw them if you asked for them. As far as I recall, RMS had some heuristics so that directory specs in output files use the same sort of brackets that were used for input files. My approach to setting my default dir to use angle brackets made that the case even for current-directory filenames (no directory actually typed).

Comment: Regarding usability: Allowing `/` as a filename character allowed using dates in filenames.

Comment: @Barmar but not times ...

Comment: ISO86901 doesn't use `/`, also middle endian dates are an abomonation.

Comment: As a 1980s office person...  The interpretation of 'Finance/Housing' depends on your pronunciation.  "Finance slash Housing" is the Finance intersect Housing category.  "Finance stroke Housing" is the Housing subcategory of Finance.